# What is Linux' slogan, if there is any?

Tags: linux, history

I'd love to know if there is any slogan of linux?

Comment: If this were asking about _operating system distributions_ then there'd be answers that could be objectively supported.  But you've asked about the operating system _kernel_.

Comment: No I didn't asked for specific distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a open questions (please edit):

- break free from front-monotomy (linux libertine)
- Those that can, do. Those that can't, complain. (linus torvalds)
- Linux, what else ?
- Think different, think Linux
- think better, with Linux
- think the best, think Linux
- Love the best, think Linux
- With Linux, Yes you can!
- Linux: just boot it...

t-shirt:

- Try Me (Tux logo)  I'm Happy
- [image]

Anti-windows linux slogans

- In a world without fences, who needs gates?
- The software said: install Windows 2000 or better; I installed Linux.

Answer (score 6):

> Software is like sex; it's better when it's free.

- Linus Torvalds
  https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds